# STS spring bean configuration file doesn't have spring xsd namespace

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I've created a maven project in STS based on a video training tutorial and I've gone through all the steps exactly .

According to the tutorial , after adding a `spring bean configuration` file , I expect in the namespace tab , be able to choose some namespace like `mvc` and `context` , But I don't know why there is not . Just `Bean` , `C` , `P` and `Util` namespaces.

I've done some googling and others mentioned maybe it's because you don't have spring jars in your project , But as you can see It's a maven project and it's downloaded correctly .

[image]

Comment: I know it's an old topic but did you find a solution ?

Comment: Yes, check my response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need import spring library. Each library that compose Spring add a new xsd schema.
If you want have all the possible schemas add the next to your POM file:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

The before xml code not import all Spring libraries into your project. You need add one by one the spring libraries that you need. After that you will see all the schemas you can use with Spring.

This is a POM example for you:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>SL14-04</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <org.springframework-version>4.3.10.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.8.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.25</org.slf4j-version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.5.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>${java.version}</source>
                  <target>${java.version}</target>
                  <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                  <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                  <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                  <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
              </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the project and opening it again in STS. Right click on the project and select Maven -> update project. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In pom.xml you need to add spring-bean, spring context, spring context support dependencies as compatible to your spring version.